# How to write Junit test cases for EntityManger createNativeQuery with String and class as parameters

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, junit, mockito

```java
@Repository
public class DesignatorDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl implements DesignatorDao {

    @Autowired
    EntityManager em;

    public List<Designator> getDesignators(DesignatorRequestDTO dto) throws Exception {
        List<Designator> designatorsList = new ArrayList<>();
        int start = dto.getStart();
        String queryString ="select * from ( SELECT * FROM TAB.DESIGNATOR WHERE ACTIVE_IND ='A' ORDER BY LAST_EDITED_DATE DESC ) OFFSET "+ start +" ROWS FETCH NEXT "+dto.getLimit()+" ROWS ONLY";          
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(queryString,Designator.class);
        designatorsList = query.getResultList();
        return designatorsList;
    }
}
```

I have the above class to get records from DB. I wrote JUnit test for this above class as

```java
@Transactional
@Rollback(true)
public class DesignatorDaoImplTest {

    @Mock
    EntityManager entityManagerMock;

    @Mock
    TypedQuery<Designator> getQuery;

    @InjectMocks
    DesignatorDaoImpl designatorDaoImpl;

    DesignatorRequestDTO dto = new DesignatorRequestDTO();

    List<Designator> designatorEntityList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception { 
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        dto.setLimit(4);
        dto.setStart(1);

        Designator entity = new Designator();
        entity.setId("dgbkk");
        designatorEntityList.add(entity);
    }

    @Test
    public void saveDesignatorTest() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(entityManagerMock.createNamedQuery(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.eq(Designator.class))).thenReturn(getQuery);
        Mockito.when(getQuery.getResultList()).thenReturn(designatorEntityList);
        assertNotNull(designatorDaoImpl.saveDesignators(dto));
    }
}
```

I have problem mocking and at this `em.createNativeQuery(queryString,Designator.class)` in dao class I am getting `null`. How can I properly mock the `em.createNativeQuery` in test class?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, *if you are using argument matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers*. Hence, try using `ArgumentMatchers.eq()` ([reference documentation](https://site.mockito.org/javadoc/current/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#eq(T))) to check for `Designator.class` equality:

```java
@Mock
TypedQuery<Designator> getQuery;

@Test
public void saveDesignatorTest() throws Exception {
    Mockito.when(entityManagerMock.createNamedQuery(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.eq(Designator.class))).thenReturn(getQuery);
    Mockito.when(getQuery.getResultList()).thenReturn(designatorEntityList);
    assertNotNull(designatorDaoImpl.getDesignators(dto));
}
```

---

Avoid using property injection and use constructor injection instead:

```java
@Repository
public class DesignatorDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl implements DesignatorDao {

    private EntityManager em;

    public DesignatorDaoImpl(EntityManager em) {
        super();
        this.em = em;
    }

    public List<Designator> getDesignators(DesignatorRequestDTO dto) throws Exception {
        List<Designator> designatorsList = new ArrayList<>();
        int start = dto.getStart();
        String queryString ="select * from ( SELECT * FROM TAB.DESIGNATOR WHERE ACTIVE_IND ='A' ORDER BY LAST_EDITED_DATE DESC ) OFFSET "+ start +" ROWS FETCH NEXT "+dto.getLimit()+" ROWS ONLY";          
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(queryString,Designator.class);
        designatorsList = query.getResultList();
        return designatorsList;
    }
}
```

Then you need to drop `@InjectMocks` because you are injecting them before being initialized and create the instance of `DesignatorDaoImpl` to test in the `@Before` method:

```java
@Transactional
@Rollback(true)
public class DesignatorDaoImplTest {

    @Mock
    EntityManager entityManagerMock;

    @Mock
    TypedQuery<Designator> getQuery;

    DesignatorDaoImpl designatorDaoImpl;

    DesignatorRequestDTO dto = new DesignatorRequestDTO();
    List<Designator> designatorEntityList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception { 
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        
        dto.setLimit(4);
        dto.setStart(1);

        Designator entity = new Designator();
        entity.setId("dgbkk");
        designatorEntityList.add(entity);

        designatorDaoImpl = new DesignatorDaoImpl(entityManagerMock);
    }

    @Test
    public void saveDesignatorTest() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(entityManagerMock.createNamedQuery(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.eq(Designator.class))).thenReturn(getQuery);
        Mockito.when(getQuery.getResultList()).thenReturn(designatorEntityList);
        assertNotNull(designatorDaoImpl.saveDesignators(dto));
    }
}
```

---

If you can't change `DesignatorDaoImpl` then use `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` instead of `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`as follows:

```java
@Transactional
@Rollback(true)
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class DesignatorDaoImplTest {

    @Mock
    EntityManager entityManagerMock;

    @Mock
    TypedQuery<Designator> getQuery;

    @InjectMocks
    DesignatorDaoImpl designatorDaoImpl;

    DesignatorRequestDTO dto = new DesignatorRequestDTO();

    List<Designator> designatorEntityList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception { 
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        dto.setLimit(4);
        dto.setStart(1);

        Designator entity = new Designator();
        entity.setId("dgbkk");
        designatorEntityList.add(entity);
    }

    @Test
    public void saveDesignatorTest() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(entityManagerMock.createNamedQuery(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.eq(Designator.class))).thenReturn(getQuery);
        Mockito.when(getQuery.getResultList()).thenReturn(designatorEntityList);
        assertNotNull(designatorDaoImpl.saveDesignators(dto));
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried you response, still getting null at  em.createNativeQuery(queryString,Designator.class);

Comment: Then can you please show the complete class under test and also the unit test class? Thanks!

Comment: updated full classes

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check it ;)

Comment: unfortunately,i can't make any changes in dao class

Comment: I've added another possibility. Please check it ;)